# Graph minor vs topological graph minor

Tags: graph-theory

I still have problem with the notion of a minor versus a topological minor.

> 1. Prove that $K_7$ has $K_4$ as a topological minor.
> 2. Let $v_1,...,v_6$ a labeling of $K_6$ and let $G$ be the graph obtained from $K_6$ by removing the edges $\{v_1v_2,v_1v_3,v_4v_5, v_4v_6\}$. Prove that $G$ contain $K_5$ as a minor but not as a topological minor.

**My Answers:**

> 1. Be deleting $3$ vertices of $K_7$ we obtain $K_4$ and thus $K_4$ is a topological minor of $K_7$.
> 2. By contracting the edge $v_1v_4$ we obtain $K_5$. Therefore $K_5$ is a minor of $G$. Since the vertices $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$ and $v_5$ each have degree $4$ and vertices $v_1$ and $v_4$ each have degree $3$, it's impossible for $K_5$ to be a topological minor of $G$ because if it were, at least five vertices need to have degree $4$.

Are my arguments correct?

Comment: Are my arguments corrects ?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I'll include the definitions of *graph minor* and *topological graph minor*, but yes, your arguments are sound.

> We say that a graph $H$ is a **minor** of $G$ (sometimes denoted $H \prec G$) if you can form $H$ by deleting vertices, deleting edges, or [contracting edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) in $G$.
>
> We say that $H$ is a **topological minor** of $G$ if there exists a [subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs) of $G$ (the result of deleting edges and vertices in $G$) that is isomorphic to a [subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) of $H$.

Comment: It seems that topologicl minor is belong to minor?